# Как отрендерить страницу с картой сайта на Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, express

Есть сайт на  Express.js, шаблонизатор - ejs. Как правильно скормить ему sitemap.xml и robots.txt?
Я пытался сделать так, но ничего не получилось, открывается просто страница с текстом и не проходит проверку на карту сайта. -

```
app.get('/sitemap.xml', (req, res) => {
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'sitemap.xml');
      res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
      res.sendFile(filePath);
    });
```

Comment: не проходит проверку с какой диагностикой?

Comment: сайт https://www.websiteplanet.com/ru/webtools/sitemap-validator/ 
Если туда кинуть ссылку с сайтом, то он показывает, корректно или нет отображается карта сайта. 
Почему-то, моя карта отображается вот так -
 https://service.uventa.com/zamena-i-remont-generatora 0.8 https://service.uventa.com/korporativnie-klienti 0.8 
А должна вот так 
 <url>
    <loc>https://service.uventa.com/zamena-i-remont-generatora</loc>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://service.uventa.com/korporativnie-klienti</loc>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>

Comment: проверьте в другом валидаторе. например, https://webmaster.yandex.ru/tools/sitemap/?tab=url&sitemapUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.uventa.com%2Fsitemap.xml

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже дело еще и в браузере Firefox. Упорно отказывается показывать нормальный код.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/sitemap.xml', (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'sitemap.xml');
  res.type('application/xml');
  res.sendFile(filePath, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Из описания задачи следует, что достаточно раздавать оба файла как статику, закинув в папку static.

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```